# Comparing two independent proportions

Tags: proportion, independence

Led Zeppelin's first album consisted of nine songs. The length of these songs averaged 299 seconds, with a standard deviation of 132 seconds. Their last album consisted of eight songs; they averaged 247 seconds in length, with a standard deviation of 59 seconds. Does this prove that the average lengths of songs written by the band were different at the end of their career than they had been at the beginning? State and test appropriate hypotheses.

Comment: Is this self-study?

Comment: it is a school question, just spent hours on it and don't think I'll figure out the answer

Comment: @Michael *All* questions that are put in the imperative voice are automatically considered [tag:self-study] until proven otherwise and should be processed (i.e., voted on) accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Statistical calculations and inference can help you analyze data from a sample and make conclusions (with specified uncertainty) about the population the data were sampled from.

Are you using data from two albums to make a general conclusions about many albums? Or are you just asked to comment on the data at hand? The latter does not benefit from any statistical calculations.

Comment: I think I'm supposed to do some sort of comparison to test the null hypothesis.

Comment: The point is that for all we know you might very well be looking at *all* the songs the band wrote early in its career and *all* the songs it wrote later.  The former average 299 seconds and the latter, 247 seconds.  *A fortiori*, the latter songs were shorter.  There's nothing to test, there's no statistical model.  (Some good intro stats textbooks make a point of showing how questions like this often are misguided.  That's not a reflection on you--but if your school insists on applying a hypothesis test here, you can take it as being critical of your school.)

Comment: I figured out the problem: